# Can I swap the lock out on one suspension fork for the remote lock out on another?

Tags: suspension

Both forks are rockshox. One has lock out, the other has remote lock out. Can I swap them around, and is it easy or are any special tools needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, assuming they are both remote capable. Rockshox uses the same lockout on all the models I have seen. Should be no issue and will only take a small allen wrench. You will likely need to remove the grips, brake lever and shifter from your left handlebar.

IF the new fork is not capable you may need a remote lockout top cap, which is a bigger question.

Comment: Rockshox now offer a number of different systems.

Answer (score 1):

Rockshox have three different damper compression systems and remote kits. It is possible that if you have a compatible kit you could transfer it. You have to swap the standard motion control compression damper for a remote motion control compression damper. This wouldn't require any special tools but would require a reasonable level of ability. It may also involve topping up specialised suspension oil if any is lost.

The systems are PushLoc, PopLoc and XLoc.

- PushLoc for Revelation, Reba, and SID with Motion Control DNA
- PopLoc for Tora XC, Recon Silver, Recon XC, Recon Gold and Sektor
- XLoc for Revelation, 2012 SID WC, Reba, SID 120